# How to stop service when home button pressed?

Tags: android, android-studio, service, android-mediaplayer, android-homebutton

I'm currently working on a mobile app as a final project in my course. My problem here is the background music I play using Service didn't stop when I pressed the HOME button of the phone.

BgMusicService.class

```
package com.example.biowit;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class BgMusicService extends Service {
MediaPlayer player;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bg_music);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.setVolume(100, 100);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> player.release());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    player.start();
    player.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> player.release());
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
}

}
```

No ERROR LOG detected

Comment: To be clear you want to shut down service when your app stops being in foreground?

Comment: I want to stop the service when the app is being in foreground and when returns, the service continues.

Comment: It's a service It won't get stopped.  Try stopSelf() ,. StopForeground(true)

Comment: Get rid of the service. The *point* behind the service is to do work *in the background*. If all you are doing is playing music in the foreground, you do not need a service.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **Activity lifecycle** methods call intent that will start/stop service, or even better instead of start/stopping whole service just send intent to play pause music and keep service running.

Depending on your app structure either go for `onPause/onResume` or `onStart/onStop`

Comment: `onUserLeaveHint` might be even better